# Why is there a space in sys.argv[]?

Tags: python

```
argc = len(sys.argv)

if (argc < 3 or argc > 5):
    printusage()
    sys.exit()

insensitive = 1 if ("-i" in sys.argv) else 0
boundaries = 1 if ("-b" in sys.argv) else 0

filename = sys.argv[argc-2]
str = sys.argv[argc-1]

print "Looking for '", str , "' in '" , filename , "'"
```

The output is

> python count_words.py -b -i football.txt goal
>
> Looking for ' goal ' in ' football.txt '

Why is there a space before and after 'goal' and 'football.txt' ? When I try to print the *str* and *filename* variable by themselves, they don't have these spaces.

I've also tried using str.strip() in the print, but to no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `if 5 < argc < 3:` in python.

Comment: 5 < argc < 3 will never be true ... as it would be equivalent to `5 < argc and argc < 3`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space is not in `sys.argv`, it is caused by the use of commas when printing. Try

```
print "Looking for '%s' in '%s'" % (str, filename)
```

And try to avoid shadowing the builtin `str`.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're passing separate strings to the print statement, rather than concatenating them into one string and printing it in one go:

```
>>> print "a", "b"
a b
>>> print "a" + "b"
ab
```

Note that concatenating strings is relatively expensive:  It's better to use interpolation, like this:

```
>>> print "A %s with %s" % ("string", "placeholders")
A string with placeholders
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the commas in your print statement. If you use the following it'll work:

print "Looking for '%s' in '%s'" %(str, filename)

Answer (score 2):

The `print` statement prints a space between each of its arguments. See the documentation for the [print statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

> A space is written before each object is (converted and) written, unless the output system believes it is positioned at the beginning of a line.

You could try using string concatenation instead:

```
print "Looking for '" + s + "' in '" + filename + "'"
```

or better yet, use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
print "Looking for '{0}' in '{1}'".format(s, filename)
```

Note: avoid using `str` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already answered your spaces question.

Some other suggestions:

str() is a built-in function so don't assign anything to it or you may wonder later why it doesn't work when you want to use it.

Also:

```
insensitive = 1 if ("-i" in sys.argv) else 0
```

is pretty much same as:

```
insensitive = "-i" in sys.argv
```

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion, instead of parsing the argv by yourself, you should try `OptionParser` that let you handle linux style option/flags.

```
from optparse import OptionParser
PARSER = OptionParser(usage="""usage: %%prog [-b] file_name""")
PARSER.add_option("-b", "--boundaries", action="store_true", dest="boundaries", help="Boundaries ?")
options, arguments = PARSER.parse_args()
if options.boundaries:
    # -b was activated...
file_name = arguments[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Print separates its arguments with a space. Better use str.format.